# What is bad about session storage to maintain state?

Tags: php, session, cookies

It's truly the best between cookies and session storage. It not is more secure but also is better and easier at maintaining state of the current user session. But I'd like to hear the pros and cons of using either session storing or cookies for maintaining the state of the current user session.

Comment: *"Why is everyone against session storage to maintain state?"* - Huh? For a minute, I thought this was a probable [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com) post.

Comment: An alternative would be to make your web application stateless.  A stateless session starts to become more attractive when you are running your webapp across several nodes, behind a load balancer.

Comment: why the mysql and mysqli tags? There should have been "sessions" and "cookies" as tags.

Comment: everyone who???

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner It's a legitmate question, probably asking about whether to use a database or session to persist user session data in a webapp.  But it's so poorly written that I feel no motivation to give an answer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sure I'll agree it's legit, just not the tags used and which for me, the question's unclear along with being probably too broad *and* opinion-based, IMHO.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I see that the question was rather lacking on both information and a more non-biased point of view so I have edited the question in hopes that i can get an idea as to what the benefits and detriments to using either session storage and cookies.

Comment: It was unclear (for me) with the original tags used. Now that makes more sense.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I respect the criticism. At the time, I had thought the question was worded well but now I've seen that it was too odd. I will be more careful with the wording.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, no it isn't, and here's why:  "it's a matter of *trust."*

The information that a *server* keeps "in a 'session'" is intended for use by the server only.  Indeed, the client-side must be presumed to be *malicious.*

The only thing that the server may presume to receive from the client is a "cookie value" that must mean nothing to the client, and must convey no information at all to him.  But even so the server must consider that the cookie-value might be fake, or stolen.

Therefore, "client-side session storage" is useful only for "client-side purposes," and the client is entirely responsible for it.  The server must never rely on it – at all.

Answer (score 0):

It is universally accepted by Computer Scientist. The method to use this is entirely convoluted, to say the least, but it is rather more secure that to use cookies. The more redundant aspect is that cookies and session storage both actually generate a cookie that is loaded onto the client-side that the user may see if they know how to find it. The only difference is that the cookie that is loaded by a session_start call is that the cookie is temporary.

Answer (score 0):

I have to say that session is the very best at passing state. First, it is more secure than Cookies since they are always able to inject malicious code into cookies which put our clients at risk. Second, Nobody uses cookies anymore because of the negative stigma behind therefore not useful for making an application with cookies since the user will simply turn them off. For those saying cookies are good are the programmers who are used to them and simply don't want to move on. Code evolves we also have to.